# Install OpenCV on Mac OS X Lion (10.8.2) with Xcode 4.6

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, compilation, cmake

My steps for installing OpenCV on my Machine (MBP, 15", 2.5 GHz i7, 16GB RAM, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, 128GB SSD)

1. i install git command line tools
2. latest macports version installed
3. cmake installed with `$ sudo port install cmake`
4. clone repo of opencv  `$ git clone git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git`
5. after repo is on my machine, I changed to this directory and make a new directory

   `$ cd opencv $ mkdir build  $ cd build`
6. then I run `$ cmake -G “Unix Makefiles” ../`
7. after that I get

   `-- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
   --   package 'libdc1394-2' not found
   -- checking for module 'libdc1394'
   --   package 'libdc1394' not found
   -- checking for module 'libv4l1'
   --   package 'libv4l1' not found
   -- Looking for linux/videodev.h
   -- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
   -- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
   -- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - not found
   -- Looking for sys/videoio.h
   -- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
   -- checking for module 'libavcodec'
   --   package 'libavcodec' not found
   -- checking for module 'libavformat'
   --   package 'libavformat' not found
   -- checking for module 'libavutil'
   --   package 'libavutil' not found
   -- checking for module 'libswscale'
   --   package 'libswscale' not found
   -- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
   -- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - not found
   -- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
   -- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
   -- Could NOT find PythonLibs: Found unsuitable version "2.7.2", but required is exact version "2.7.3" (found /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "", line 1, in 
   ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils

   ### -- Found apache ant 1.8.2: /usr/bin/ant

   -- General configuration for OpenCV 2.4.9 =====================================

   ### --   Version control:               2.4.4-642-g061dd7e

   --   Platform:
   --     Host:                        Darwin 12.2.0 i386
   --     CMake:                       2.8.10
   --     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
   --     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make

   ### --     Configuration:               Release

   --   C/C++:
   --     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
   --     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.2.0)
   --     C++ flags (Release):         -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
   --     C++ flags (Debug):           -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
   --     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
   --     C flags (Release):           -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
   --     C flags (Debug):             -W -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-omit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -msse3 -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -ggdb3
   --     Linker flags (Release):
   --     Linker flags (Debug):

   ### --     Precompiled headers:         NO

   --   OpenCV modules:
   --     To be built:                 core imgproc flann highgui features2d calib3d ml video objdetect contrib nonfree photo legacy gpu java softcascade stitching ts videostab
   --     Disabled:                    world
   --     Disabled by dependency:      -

   ### --     Unavailable:                 androidcamera ocl python

   --   GUI: 
   --     QT 4.x:                      NO
   --     Cocoa:                       YES

   ### --     OpenGL support:              NO

   --   Media I/O: 
   --     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.7)
   --     JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
   --     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.2.1)
   --     PNG:                         build (ver 1.5.12)
   --     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
   --     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)

   ### --     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)

   --   Video I/O:
   --     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
   --     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
   --     FFMPEG:                      YES
   --       codec:                     YES (ver Unknown)
   --       format:                    YES (ver Unknown)
   --       util:                      YES (ver Unknown)
   --       swscale:                   YES (ver Unknown)
   --       gentoo-style:              YES
   --     OpenNI:                      NO
   --     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
   --     PvAPI:                       NO
   --     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
   --     QuickTime:                   NO
   --     QTKit:                       YES

   ### --     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/NO

   --   Other third-party libraries:
   --     Use IPP:                     NO
   --     Use Eigen:                   NO
   --     Use TBB:                     NO
   --     Use OpenMP:                  NO
   --     Use GCD                      YES
   --     Use Concurrency              NO
   --     Use C=:                      NO
   --     Use Cuda:                    NO

   ### --     Use OpenCL:                  NO

   --   Python:

   ### --     Interpreter:                 /opt/local/bin/python2 (ver 2.7.3)

   --   Java:
   --     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.8.2)
   --     JNI:                         /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers

   ### --     Java tests:                  YES

   --   Documentation:
   --     Build Documentation:         NO
   --     Sphinx:                      NO

   ### --     PdfLaTeX compiler:           NO

   --   Tests and samples:
   --     Tests:                       YES
   --     Performance tests:           YES

   ### --     C/C++ Examples:              NO

   ### --   Install path:                  /usr/local

   --   cvconfig.h is in:              /Users/miralemcebic/Desktop/ocv/opencv/build

   ### -- -----------------------------------------------------------------

   -- Configuring done
   -- Generating done
   -- Build files have been written to: /Users/miralemcebic/Desktop/ocv/opencv/build`
8. than I run `$ cmake -G “Unix Makefiles” ../`
9. Now here comes the errors and of the end by 30% I get this

   `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.9.dylib] Error 1
   make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
   make: *** [all] Error 2`

What is here the Problem? I also have Python 2.7 and Python >3

Can anybody help me by this issue?

Comment: chances are good, you miss ffmpeg (espacially libavcodec), if it is installed make sure you have static libraries compiled too (libavcodec.a)

Comment: Install ffmpeg by pasting the following command in the terminal application: 
$ sudo port install ffmpeg +gpl +postproc +lame +theora +libogg +vorbis+xvid +x264 +a52 +faac +faad +dts +nonfree

Answer (score 3):

Install [macports](http://macports.org)

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port install opencv
```

Wait.

Comment: Miralems-MacBookPro:~ miralemcebic$ sudo port selfupdate
Password:
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 installed,
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree

Miralems-MacBookPro:~ miralemcebic$ sudo port install opencv
--->  Computing dependencies for opencv
--->  Cleaning opencv
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
Miralems-MacBookPro:~ miralemcebic$ 
 and this is it?

Comment: @Mir23 I don't know if that's it or not; you might want to test it and tell me.

Comment: Are you get dylib ? in /usr/local/lib or have you a .framework?

Comment: Macports installs into `/opt/local/lib`, not `/usr/local/lib` and I've never installed it myself, so I don't know if you get static or dynamic libraries.  You might want to use a *variant* if you want things like Python integration (i.e. `sudo port install opencv +python27`).  See `$ port info opencv` for details.